# Need the phone number to compile woth a phrase and not just the number

Tags: java

This is my code

```
import java.util.*;
public class PhoneKeypad {

public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.print("Enter an uppercase letter ");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String phNumber = input.next();

    String output = "";

    for(int i = 0 ; i < phNumber.length() ; i++){

        char ch = Character.toUpperCase(phNumber.charAt(i));

        if(Character.isLetter(ch)){
            int digit = getNumber(ch);

            output = output + digit;

        }

        else{

            output = output + ch;

        }

    }

      System.out.println(output);

}

public static int getNumber(char upperCaseLetter){

    if(upperCaseLetter == 'A' || upperCaseLetter == 'B'

                                || upperCaseLetter == 'C')

        return "The Corresponding number is 2";

    else if(upperCaseLetter == 'D' || upperCaseLetter == 'E'

                                     || upperCaseLetter == 'F')

        return "The Corresponding number is 3";

    else if(upperCaseLetter == 'G' || upperCaseLetter == 'H'

                                     || upperCaseLetter == 'I')

        return "The Corresponding number is 4";

    else if(upperCaseLetter == 'J' || upperCaseLetter == 'K'

                                     || upperCaseLetter == 'L')

        return  "The Corresponding number is 5";

    else if(upperCaseLetter == 'M' || upperCaseLetter =='N'

                                     || upperCaseLetter == 'O')

        return 6 "The Corresponding number is 6";

    else if(upperCaseLetter == 'P' || upperCaseLetter == 'Q'

                                     || upperCaseLetter == 'R')

        return "The Corresponding number is 7";

    else if(upperCaseLetter == 'S' || upperCaseLetter =='T'

                                     || upperCaseLetter == 'U')

        return "The Corresponding number is 8";
    else if(upperCaseLetter == 'V' || upperCaseLetter == 'W'

          || upperCaseLetter == 'Y' || upperCaseLetter == 'Z')

        return "The Corresponding number is 9";

    else

        return 0;

}
```

}

This gives me errors. I need the output to say the corresponding number is _
and not just the number

These are the types of errors I am getting

```
PhoneKeypad.java:67: error: ';' expected
            return 6 "The Corresponding number is 6";
                    ^
PhoneKeypad.java:69: error: 'else' without 'if'
        else if(upperCaseLetter == 'P' || upperCaseLetter == 'Q'
        ^
PhoneKeypad.java:69: error: illegal start of type
        else if(upperCaseLetter == 'P' || upperCaseLetter == 'Q'
             ^
PhoneKeypad.java:69: error: <identifier> expected
        else if(upperCaseLetter == 'P' || upperCaseLetter == 'Q'
               ^
PhoneKeypad.java:69: error: ';' expected
        else if(upperCaseLetter == 'P' || upperCaseLetter == 'Q'
                ^
PhoneKeypad.java:69: error: illegal start of type
        else if(upperCaseLetter == 'P' || upperCaseLetter == 'Q'
                                ^
PhoneKeypad.java:69: error: <identifier> expected
        else if(upperCaseLetter == 'P' || upperCaseLetter == 'Q'
                                  ^
PhoneKeypad.java:69: error: ';' expected
        else if(upperCaseLetter == 'P' || upperCaseLetter == 'Q'
                                      ^
PhoneKeypad.java:69: error: <identifier> expected
        else if(upperCaseLetter == 'P' || upperCaseLetter == 'Q'
                                                         ^
PhoneKeypad.java:69: error: illegal start of type
        else if(upperCaseLetter == 'P' || upperCaseLetter == 'Q'
                                                             ^
```

Comment: Here's where careful code formatting **really** helps. Consider trying this (or using an IDE).

Comment: Why are you returning strings from a method that's supposed to return `int`?

Comment: How can I change it them so I can return strings instead of just int

Comment: `return 6 "The Corresponding number is 6";` makes no sense, may be `return 6;` or `return "The Corresponding number is 6";` depending on what you actually want to return from the method

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend downloading an IDE such as "Eclipse" to help you write your code. It will pinpoint a lot of the errors that are present in your code.

```
public static int getNumber(char upperCaseLetter)
```

As for your question, remove the `int`and replace it with either 'String' or 'void'

Comment: When I do that I get this as an error:    PhoneKeypad.java:37: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
    public static  getNumber(char upperCaseLetter){
                   ^
1 error

Comment: are you using Eclipse or any similar IDE? If you hover your mouse over the error it will offer you suggestions. Try replacing 'int' with 'void'.

Answer (score 0):

Look at line 67. You have `return 6 "The Corresponding number is 6";` when you should have `return "The Corresponding number is 6";`

If you want to return Strings instead of ints just change the method signature.
i.e. `public static String getNumber(char upperCaseLetter){` instead of `public static int getNumber(char upperCaseLetter){`

Comment: These errors come up when I do that:        PhoneKeypad.java:19: error: incompatible types
                int digit = getNumber(ch);
                                     ^
  required: int
  found:    String
PhoneKeypad.java:88: error: incompatible types
            return 0;
                   ^
  required: String
  found:    int

Comment: You're going to have to put a bit of effort into this yourself. If you're assigning a String to an int you're going to get the compiler error that says an int was found when a String was required. If you change the return type you're going to have to change the returns.

Answer (score 0):

Your return values for getNumber are Strings, but the method, as well as your main method, expects an int value. For example, the following should work better:

```
public static int getNumber(char upperCaseLetter) {
    if (
            upperCaseLetter == 'A' 
            || upperCaseLetter == 'B' 
            || upperCaseLetter == 'C') {
        return 2;
    } else if (
            upperCaseLetter == 'D' 
            || upperCaseLetter == 'E' 
            || upperCaseLetter == 'F') {
        return 3;
    }
    //etc.
    return 0;       
}
```

However, since you use that many if / else if in this method, you could also consider using a switch case:

```
public static int getNumber2(char upperCaseLetter) {
    switch (upperCaseLetter) {
        case 'A':case 'B':case 'C':
            return 2;
        case 'D':case 'E':case 'F':
            return 3;
        //etc.
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```